# How do I scroll to an ExpandItem in an ExpandBar?

Tags: java, swt, scrollbar

If I have more expand items than fills the client area of an expand bar, how can I scroll to a particular item and place it at the top of the client area? There doesn't appear to be an appropriate scrollTo() or makeVisible() method on either ExpandBar or ExpandItem so I am not sure what method I should be using.

I tried getting the expand bar's vertical scroll bar and setting its selection which works except that the bar's contents are not scrolled even though the scroll bar thumb moves to the correct position.

Is this a bug? What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

> There doesn't appear to be an appropriate scrollTo() or makeVisible() method on either ExpandBar

Instead of trying to handle the scrolling aspect at the ExpandBar level, have you taken a look at [ScrolledComposite.setOrigin(Point)](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/ScrolledComposite.html#setOrigin(org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point))?

You can then get the location of the desired ExpandItem via `expandItem.getControl().getLocation()` and use that point on the above method.